# How to make a web page into a android app

Tags: java, android, xml

Hi I'm trying to make a web based app but i'm a beginner and not 100% sure what i'm doing right now please could you guide me there are no errors but it says the app is not responding when I run it

---

Main Java

---

```
    package com.theverge.www.theverge;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    import static com.theverge.www.theverge.R.id.*;


    public class TheVerge extends Activity {

        private WebView the_verge;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_verge);

             the_verge = (WebView) findViewById(activity_the_verge_webview);
            // Enable Javascript
            WebSettings webSettings = the_verge.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
            the_verge.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            the_verge.loadUrl("http://www.theverge.com");
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_the_verge, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

---

Here is the xml for the main activity

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_the_verge_webview"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".TheVerge">

    <TextView android:text="" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

---

The AndroidManfest xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.theverge.www.theverge" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TheVerge"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a WebView to your layout file. Change it to something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/activity_the_verge_webview"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".TheVerge">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

And then replace your `onCreate()` method with this one

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_verge);

         the_verge = (WebView) findViewById(webView1);
        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = the_verge.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        the_verge.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        the_verge.loadUrl("http://www.theverge.com");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to asign your relativelayout to a webview variable here:
   the_verge = (WebView) findViewById(activity_the_verge_webview);

1. You need to add a webview to the layout and give it a id
2. Asign the webview variable to the id you just used in 1.

Also if you plugin your device to a computer you get a crashlog in your program :)

Answer (score 1):

You have defined textview instead of webview in your xml.Try this out...

xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
android:id="@+id/webView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_name);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

}

}
```